# Gremlin console keeps returning "Connection to server is no longer active" error

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I tried to run a Gremlin query adding a property to vertex through Gremlin console.

`g.V().hasLabel("user").has("status", "valid").property(single, "type", "valid")`

I constantly get this error:
`org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.console.RemoteException: Connection to server is no longer active`

This error happens after query is running for one or two minutes.

I tried some simple queries like `g.V().limit(10)` and it works fine.
Since the affected vertex count is more than 4 million, not sure if it is failing due to timeout issue.

I also tried to split it into small batches:
`g.V().hasLabel("user").has("status", "valid").hasNot("type").limit(200000).property(single, "type", "valid")`
It succeeded for first few batches and started failing again.

Is there any recommendations for updating millions of vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise approach you take may vary depending on the backend graph database and storage you are using as well as the capacity of the hardware being used.

The capacity of the hardware where Gremlin Server is running in terms of number of CPUs and most importantly, memory, will also be a factor as will the setting of the query timeout value.

To do this in Gremlin, if you had a way to identify distinct ranges of vertices easily you could split this up into multiple threads each doing batches of updates. If the example you show is representative of your actual need then that is likely not possible in this case.

Likewise some graph databases provide a bulk load capability that is often a good way to do large batch updates but probably not an option here as you need to do essentially a conditional update based on looking at the current presence (or not) of a property.

Without more information about your data model and hardware etc. the best answer is probably to do two things:

1. Use smaller limits. Maybe try 5K or even just 1K at first and work up from there until you find a reliable sweet spot.
2. Increase the query timeout settings.

You may need to experiment to find the sweet spot for your environment as the capacity of the hardware will definitely play a role in situations like this as well as how you write your query.

Comment: I am having similar issue, however in this case my query is around 131KB long, which gives this error when running the query. Query looks sth like this -  `g.addV('sampleNode').property('id', '6a731d2e-aef1-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004').property('Name', 'Sample').property('Description', 'Sample').property('Columns', '<Long string>').property('pk', 'SamplePK')`

Comment: It would be good to start a new question with more information about your database configuration and other use case specific items @codeomnitrix

Comment: Got the solution its due to message size script when using gremlin client the protocol only supports 128kb from cosmos db side for query string length.